# Getting the device interface orientation in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I need to get the interface orientation in the viewWillAppear method of my UIViewController. What I did is:

```
if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
   NSLog(@"Portrait");
else
   NSLog(@"Landscape");
```

When in landscape, I'm always getting Portrait in the viewWillAppear and Landscape in the viewDidAppear. Why?

So, I tried using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation], but the same happens. I also tried another solution posted here in Stack Overflow:

```
UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[device beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = device.orientation;
[device endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

This seems to correctly return the orientation, but now I'm left with the problem of mapping UIDeviceOrientation to UIInterfaceOrientation, which is not possible as far as I know (face up and face down cannot be mapped).

Any solution to this issue?

Comment: If you can support iOS 5+ it's better to do this work in the -viewWillLayoutSubviews method. If your app has just finished loading, -viewWillAppear may be called before the views frame is set and the window has finished orienting itself. If you need that info in iOS 4 you really need to wait for -viewDidAppear to be called.

Comment: If you're using a navigation controller, what about checking self.navigationController.interfaceOrientation in viewWillAppear?

Comment: @JasonCoco That is working perfectly for me. It would be interesting to find a solution for iOS4 as well but that is good.

Comment: @AntonHolmquist Tried that as well, forgot to mention. I'm still getting always portrait. Aren't you?

Comment: @JasonCoco If you answer to the question with the information you provided in the comment, I'll mark that as accepted. That is the only working option provided so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first comment by JasonCoco is the best solution I found to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation instead.

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    // Portrait
}
if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    // Landscape
}
```

Comment: As I said, I tried this. Always getting portrait. Is this working for you?